# Difference between Observer and DisposableObserver in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I know that `DisposableObserver` has implemented both of `Observer` and `Disposable`. Flagged `onSubscribe()` method as `final` and provided `onStart()` instead of it.

But I can't understand what are the differences between this two in action. And when I should use `Observer` or `DisposableObserver`?

Could you please tell the benefits or disadvantages of using these as compared to each other?

Comment: Have you read its [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal onSubscribe method of observers can be called as many as you use this same observer. but with `DisposableObserver` `onSubscibe` method can be called only once meaning that you are only allowed to use this `DisposableObserver` once. if you pass a single object of `DisposableObserver` to two stream it will throw exception and close both of them quickly. this logic has been implemented in `onSubscribe()` of this class thus you can not override it. but in case you need the `onSubscribe()` callback you can override `onStart()` method which is the same.

The usage of this class can be as follows.

As per documentation a DisposableObserver is:

> An abstract Observer that allows asynchronous cancellation by implementing Disposable.

in other words it means that you can use disposable behaviors inside your observer methods. like calling `dispose()` in `onNext()`.

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .map {
            "$it"
        }
        .subscribe(object : DisposableObserver<String>(){
            override fun onComplete() {
            }

            override fun onNext(t: String) {
                println("first item only= $t")

                //we can dispose this stream right in the observer methods
                dispose()
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }

        })
```

One may even combine `DisposableObserver` with `subscribeWith()` to get almost the same behavior as normal observers.

```
val disposableObserver = object : DisposableObserver<String>() {
        override fun onComplete() {
        }

        override fun onNext(t: String) {
            println("first item only= $t")

            //we can dispose this stream right in the observer methods
            dispose()
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        }

    }

    val disposable: Disposable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .map {
            "$it"
        }
        .subscribeWith(disposableObserver)

    disposable.dispose()
```

This and many other classes and operators in RX-Java are there to ease the use of RX and depending on how you want to use the library any of them can be chosen.